# VirtualBox and VBoxVmService networking

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm running ssh server on `VirtualBox`-ed `Slackware 14.2` on `Windows` host. I've set up `NAT networking` with port forwarding with `4191` port configured as a host port.

I've installed and configured `VBoxVmService` to automate the virtual machine startup/stop process. The problem is that although the service is successfully and automatically started on Windows startup (what i can verify with the `Task Manager`) the virtual machine networking seems not to work properly - there is no `4191` port open (i've checked with `CurrPorts` app). What's curious when i stop and start the service again using `VmServiceControl` tool the networking work as expected - the port `4191` is open and i can connect to vm ssh server.

I'm wondering why the vm networking doesn't work on system startup without the need to manually restart the `VBoxVmService` service.

Answer (score 1):

This might be an issue (or more of a feature) of Windows Firewall. The VirtualBox GUI prompts for firewall access during first-time run, but `VBoxVmService` runs the VMs using `VBoxHeadless.exe`, which might not have access yet. The solution found [here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=4762&start=225#p156928) was to allow `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe` through the firewall.

Since your issue is resolved by restarting the service after boot, you may have already done this.